# Excel Sorting withing calculated columns

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table

Maybe that is a stupid very easy question but i am trying to do a sorting within a calculated column in a pivot table and i cannot make it work.
I am trying to sort by descending orders my OOS suppliers.

See below table and i would like to sort supplier with the highest percentage in column "OOS".

[image]

I have tried to use the sort ascending descending is all the field but it seems it keep sorting using the grand totals.

Comment: You can't sort on a particular item within a column field. You'd need a separate field for OOS.

Comment: oh okay thanks a lot !